# Overwrite entire Typescript Interface with an imported Interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So I would like to override the NodeJS { ProcessENV } interface so that our code can be more rigid and people cannot go adding ENV properties that may conflict across services.  I have created an interface such as this one in a shared repo that can be imported

```
IConfigENV {
  ENV: string;
  PROP: string;
  PROP_2: string
}
```

The problem I'm seeing is that `ProcessENV extends Dict<string>`

so when I do something like

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  export interface ProcessEnv extends IConfigENV {}
}
```

it will pick up the explicit values alright however it will still allow unknown properties to be called from `process.env.UNKNOWN_PROP`.  I would love for this to fail at compile.

I noticed that there is a request on typescript to implement a spread operator for interfaces but it looks like it's not implemented.

Just wondering if anyone has found a work around to this problem or has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

No, you can't restrict that further.

#### Theory

In typescript **you can not override interfaces**, you can only extend them, and `NodeJS.ProcessEnv` is already of type

```
export interface ProcessEnv {
    [key: string]: string | undefined
}
```

So you can be explicit about new properties (they even still will be forced to satisfy existing constraint). But you can't remove this statement, what says, that any string is allowed on the ProcessEnv type and it will be of type string or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to come up with a solution that achieve the desired result even if it's not exactly what I wanted.

`const processENV: IConfigENV = process.env;`

this will only allow any properties defined on the interface to be referenced.